# IndexedDB: proper schema to map urls to accepted markdown/HTML text formatting tags

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, database, nosql

## Disclaimer

> I am very new to the concept of object oriented databases and I honestly don't
>   have much experience with relational databases either.

---

I am trying use indexedDB to store some data client side, but before I get into it. I need to decide on a proper schema.

I need to satisfy the following use case:

- I will be querying the database based on URL and I need to get back all of the tags that the website uses for markdown / HTML text formatting in its textareas. (I only need 1 set of tags for each command though)

Currently, I plan on making every url in the DB it's own dictionary key.

for example:

```
[ youtube.com:{ {command:"bold",   open:"*", close:"*" },
                {command:"italic", open:"_", close:"_" },
                ...
              },

  StackOverflow.com: { {command:"strong", open:"<strong>", close:"</strong>" },
                        .....
                     },
  .......
  .......

]
```

Can anyone point out flaws with this approach/ suggest alternatives and give explanations?

For performance reasons, I may end up changing the inner most dictionaries to arrays, but I am looking for advice on the general schema here more than on that small point. Although, advice on this would certainly be appreciated as well.

## EDIT

Now that I know about keyGen and and indexing more, I am thinking there is definitely a better way to do this. Perhaps I could make the command name itself the **keyPath** and have each object within that key consist of a set of tags and an array of urls that use that set.

**Bonus question:** 
If anyone happens to know of a way to dynamically (pragmatically) detect the markdown tags that a site uses(if it uses any) as the site is visited then I will award you with 9001 unicorn dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick guess would be a single object store where you store objects with two properties: url and tags. Given that each object is uniquely identified by a URL, the url property would be the keypath. The tags property would be a variable length array of strings. You could then have other properties but these would be the two important properties.

You can then create an index on the tags property with the multi-entry flag set to enable querying of pages by tags.

For example, in onupgradeneeded, use:

```
function onUpgradeNeeded(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var pageStore = db.createObjectStore('pages', {keyPath: 'url'});
  pageStore.createIndex('tagIndex', 'tags', {multiEntry: true});
}
```

For example, to put an object into the store:

```
function insertPage(db, page, callback) {
  var tx = db.transaction('pages','readwrite');
  tx.oncomplete = callback;
  var pageStore = tx.objectStore('pages');
  pageStore.put(page);
}

var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = onUpgradeNeeded;
openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;

  var mockPage = {
    url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
    tags: ['bold','comment','italics'],
    foo: bar
  };

  putPage(db, mockPage, function(event) {
    console.log('Completed putting %o into pages object store', mockPage);
  });
}
```

To query by url:

```
function findPageByURLThenHandle(db, url, callback, fallback) {
  var tx = db.transaction('pages','readonly');
  var pageStore = tx.objectStore('pages');
  var request = pageStore.get(url);
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var page = event.target.result;
    if(page) {
      callback(page);
    } else {
      fallback(url);
    }
  };
}

var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var queryURL = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
  var db = event.target.result;

  findPageByURLThenHandle(db, queryURL, function(page) {
    console.log('Found %o for %s', page, queryURL);
  }, function(url) {
    console.log('Could not find page for url %s', url);
  });
};
```

To find all pages with a given tag:

```
function handlePagesForTag(db, tag, callback) {
  var tx = db.transaction('pages','readonly');
  var pageStore = tx.objectStore('pages');
  var tagIndex = pageStore.index('tagIndex');
  var request = tagIndex.openCursor(tag);
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(!cursor) return;
    var page = cursor.value;
    callback(page);
    cursor.continue();
  };
}
```

Hope that helps you get started.

Comment: Very useful as an API usage example, but not as a schema suggestion. I think you misunderstood the fact that the command to make tag associated with "bold" for example, varies from page to page. Thank you though, I actually have a schema that I am currently implementing and this will help me implement it